# Retrofit @Body showing up as parameter in HTTP request

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, http-post, retrofit

I've previously used Square's **Retrofit** successfully for a `@GET` web API call but when trying to send JSON as the `@BODY` in a `@POST` call, on the server (Rails) the JSON is showing up as Parameters rather than the body request.

My understanding is that `@BODY` will add that method parameter to the request in the body.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**WebApi**:

```
@POST("/api/v1/gear/scans.json")
Response postScans(
    @Header(HEADER_AUTH) String token,
    @Body JsonObject scans
);
```

Make web request:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setServer(api_url)
    .build();
WebApi webApi = restAdapter.create(AssetsWebApi.class);     
Response response = webApi.postScans(auth_token, valid_json);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out that if you want to *POST* data as part of the request body, you need to annotate the API interface method as `@FormUrlEncoded` and pass the content of the body as a `@Field` as below:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/v1/gear/scans.json")
Response postScans(
    @Header(HEADER_AUTH) String token,
    @Field("scans") JsonArray scans
);
```

Async call for @Rickster:

```
@POST("/api/v1/gear/scans.json") 
void postScans(
    @Header(HEADER_AUTH) String token,
    @Body JsonObject scans,
    Callback<PostSuccessResponseWrapper> callback
);
```

Comment: How do you do an asynchronous version of this? When I add a callback, I get an exception - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572301/retrofit-throwing-illegalargumentexception-exception-for-asynchronous-formurlenc

Comment: @Rickster I suspect your issue is to do with your `@DELETE` annotation but I'm not familiar with that - I've only ever done `@GET` & `@POST` calls. My async call is edited above.

Comment: Great answer. It is strange though that you can not do `@Body String param_name`, but insted you have to do `@Field("param") String param_name` and before `@POST` you need to annotate `@FormUrlEncoded` ;) but because this is the perfect solution, i am ok with that. Thank You!